# Is there a report type to document a (Agile) project journey?

Tags: scrum, agile, reporting, progress-report

My main goals are to

1. document our current methodology,
2. share our team's story of changing and adapting, and
3. share evaluations of our improvement.

Ideally, I'd like to share this report with our team so they can see the journey we've been on and learn a thing or two about what we do.

At first, I thought a case study would work. I think this handles the idea behind documenting our strategies, but it doesn't touch on the story of getting to where we are. Another option I saw was a progress report. This does a better job, in my opinion, of documenting our team's story, but it lacks some of the documentation on our methodology.

Is there a report format that organizes this? I've tried writing this on my own, and I can go back to that if need be, but I always feel a pre-determined report type is easier both to write and understand. I'm still pretty new to Agile and PM as a whole, so please let me know if I'm misunderstanding a report type!

**Edit based on feedback so far:**

I think I'm leaning to write a couple of separate docs rather than one large nightmare. I could document the current methodology as an ongoing document, thinking this would be most useful when adding new team members. A presentation is a really great idea for the story part -- we're a remote team spread across nearly 20 hours of time zones, but it brings up a lot of ideas. This would help me tell the higher up guys where we started, why the project was failing, and why we're here now. The evaluations of improvement I'm referencing are much more concrete/numerical, so maybe that can be expressed in a case study.

The presentation seems to be the way to go, I upvoted that answer and will accept after working through it a little more.

Comment: What is a "project journey?" Who's the target audience? What do you hope to accomplish with this document?

Comment: @aliciasilhavy: Todd A. Jacobs is right. It's important to know why you think you need such a document and what you want to accomplish with it. You mention "Ideally, I'd like to share this report with our team so they can see the journey we've been on and learn a thing or two about what we do". Who is "our team" and who is "we"?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Project journey, to me, is the story of the changes our team has made in terms of strategy from start to now. We've changed a whole lot and I'd like a way to document that. The target audience would be stakeholders, the development team, and the supervisors of the development team (that's also our team/we). I hope to inform others of what we have changed, what our methodology is now, and evidence that what we're doing is working. Basically something to say "here's what I did to help improve the team, and here's how/why it's working."

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for a [Project Charter](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/project-chartering). This kind of documents varies a lot from project to project.

With regards to tools and techniques, I share a part of the linked article.

> The Agile community has appropriated a number of different techniques
>   or notations that have proven useful to capture high-level project
>   information. For instance the “rich picture” approach of SSM (Soft
>   Systems); the “context diagram” from structured analysis; or Lean
>   manufacturing’s A3 (which derives its name precisely from the paper
>   format).

Answer (score 1):

We conduct [risk assessments](https://teamsuccess.io/risk) during our projects. The resulting risk register enables us to share evaluations of our improvement and tells our team's story of changing and adapting.

Comment: Hi userden. How is that answering OP's question?

Comment: Hi Tiago, sorry for my short answer! I understood OP's question as to whether there is a report format to organize the team's story of improving, changing and adapting. That's why the risk assessment report format came into my mind. In our team, we often do pre-mortem and post-mortem exercises, where we talk about 'risks and opportunities'. I'm sure there are better formats, but we sometimes use the resulting high-level risk assessment report to share it with our team and managers, so they can see how we have continuously improved, changed and adapted during the project's lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @userden. It's an interesting take, +1.

Answer (score 0):

> document our current methodology

How quickly will this become out of date? Will the document be continually updated? Will enough people read the document to ensure its value? Agile teams tend to shy away from documentation unless they are sure of their value.

> share our team's story of changing and adapting

One of the Agile values is [Individuals and interactions over processes and tools](https://agilemanifesto.org/). This means we favour talking to each other. Perhaps a presentation would be a good format to achieve the sharing of the team's story?

> share evaluations of our improvement

Rather than doing this as a one-off, why not ask the team if they mind regularly sharing their retrospective output? For example, you could have an area of wall space allocated to act as an information radiator for adaptions the team has made.